# Closed XML pass Workbook.Worksheet as parameter

Tags: c#, closedxml

I have the following code:

```
    var workbook1 = new XLWorkbook(@path);
    var ws = workbook1.Worksheet(1);
```

I like to pass ws as a parameter to a method but not sure what type it is.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the interface `IXLWorksheet` for worksheets.